# Channel openning fee too low

Tags: lightning-network, fee-estimation

[image]I recently setup a bitcoin node (bitcoind) and lightning node (lnd) on a linux system. As lifetime windows user this was quite challenging!

Anyway I tried to open my first channel about 4 days ago and the transaction is still stuck in pending. I didnt set a fee manually as I had read that lnd should automatically pick one. I cant find a TXid to lookup what fee was chosen.

Is there a way I can bump up the fee or do I have to wait until it drops out of the mempool?

Next time how can I check what fee will be set and possibly adjust?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the last part of your question : "Next time how can I check what fee will be set and possibly adjust?" that depends which implementation you have installed.

For example in c-lightning from the docs at https://lightning.readthedocs.io/lightning-fundchannel.7.html we can Learn that you can use the optional feerate argument in the fund channel command:

```
feerate is an optional feerate used for the opening transaction and as initial feerate for commitment and HTLC transactions. It can be one of the strings urgent (aim for next block), normal (next 4 blocks or so) or slow (next 100 blocks or so) to use lightningd’s internal estimates: normal is the default.

Otherwise, feerate is a number, with an optional suffix: perkw means the number is interpreted as satoshi-per-kilosipa (weight), and perkb means it is interpreted bitcoind-style as satoshi-per-kilobyte. Omitting the suffix is equivalent to perkb.
```

For lnd the documentation at https://api.lightning.community/#newaddress says

```
# One can manually set the fee to be used for the funding transaction via either
# the --conf_target or --sat_per_byte arguments. This is optional.

$ lncli openchannel [command options] node-key local-amt push-amt
```